# How does server-side rendering work with Riot.js and Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, riot.js

Currently, the example on the project site shows server-side rendering of Riot.js through Node.js.

```
var riot = require('riot')
var timer = require('timer.tag')

var html = riot.render(timer, { start: 42 })

console.log(html) // <timer><p>Seconds Elapsed: 42</p></timer>
```

I want to know how it would work with Phoenix or probably Sinatra.

Comment: post some of your research efforts

Comment: I guess it would work the same

Comment: And elaborate the question.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell nobody has written a mix package to integrate with riot.js for the purpose of server-side rendering

If you're willing to explore it there is https://github.com/bryanjos/elixirscript that is an elixir wrapper for the virtual-dom. You could generate some JS with elixir and have a small node service render the markup or perhaps try something more wholesome.

Best of luck :)